# How to pass debug argument to node in windows?

Tags: node.js, powershell, terminal, environment-variables

I'm using loopback 4 and want to set some env variable values when starting up node.js. According to the docs

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Setting-debug-strings.html

I can do this on windows

```
C:\> set DEBUG=loopback:datasource
C:\> npm start
```

however, it doesn't work and doesn't print the logs that I wrote.

However if I try on git shell `mintty 3.5.0`, I can do this

```
C:\> DEBUG=loopback:datasource node .
```

and it works fine.

How can I get it to work on windows terminal? I am using PowerShell actually if that matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The above one is for CMD (which is now deprecated)

This is for powershell

```
$env:DEBUG="loopback:datasource"
npm run inspect
```